# How to enable/disable in each row of UITableview iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I need to disable/enable uibutton in each row of UItableview, I compare 2 NSMutablearray to enable/disable it.I tried below code but it always enable button in first row. Where's mistake in my code?

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d,%d",indexPath.section,indexPath.row];

    UITableViewCell *cell= [_tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];


    UIButton *pausebtn= [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier] autorelease];
        [pausebtn setFrame:CGRectMake(285, 10, 30,30)];
        [pausebtn setTag:4000];
        [pausebtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Pause.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [pausebtn addTarget:self action:@selector(pausebtnClicked:event:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:pausebtn];

    }

     pausebtn = (UIButton*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:4000];
    [pausebtn addTarget:self action:@selector(pausebtnClicked:event:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [pausebtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Pause.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

   //check 2 arrays

   if ([[Array1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] integerValue] != [[Array2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] integerValue]) 
   {
        pausebtn.enabled = YES;
   }
   else{
       pausebtn.enabled = NO;
   }


   return cell;
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: put break point on if condition and see the values of Array1 & Array 2. Your condition is always getting false.

Comment: Why addTarget and setImage every time? And what is Array1 and Array2?

Comment: @JayGajjar: My if condition is correct, i tested. Thanks

Comment: @JosonDaniel  This Not related to ur question.just in general. it seems you are not reusing the Identifier and also you creating Identifier for each cell which is wrong and inefficient way.

Answer (score 0):

Declare your UIButton before checking if cell is nil and creating it.
Create UIButton only if cell is nill
If cell already exists, get it by tag.

```
UIButton *pausebtn;

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier] autorelease];
    pausebtn= [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    .....

}
    pausebtn = (UIButton*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:4000];
    .....
```